# WPF - Assign F-keys to buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know about "_" instead of "&" but how to assign F1,F2... key to a button ?
It's a small application, i'm not using Commands just straight click event handlers but I could use commands if necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the small project I'm working on now, I have this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:CommandReference x:Key="ExitCommandReference" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
    <c:CommandReference x:Key="ReloadCommandReference" Command="{Binding ReloadCommand}" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F4" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{StaticResource ExitCommandReference}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{StaticResource ReloadCommandReference}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

And in the code:

```
private DelegateCommand exitCommand;
private DelegateCommand reloadCommand;
public ICommand ExitCommand { get { return exitCommand ?? (exitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Exit)); } }
public ICommand ReloadCommand { get { return reloadCommand ?? (reloadCommand = new DelegateCommand(Reload)); } }
private static void Exit() { Application.Current.Shutdown(); }
private void Reload() { LoadData(); }
```

Comment: Too much code IMHO; I ended up by creating a custom button class with a "Key" attached property and on PreviewKeyUp I'm searching for the first child button with the right Key property

Answer (score 7):

easily for it...
Try it on....follow me

In Xaml file:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="cmd1"></RoutedUICommand>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource cmd1}" Executed="btn_font_Click"> </CommandBinding>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding  Key="F1" Command="{StaticResource cmd1}"></KeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Button  Command="{StaticResource cmd1}" Name="btn_font" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Width="60" Height="25" Content="Enter" Click="btn_font_Click" Margin="10,2"/>
```

In Cs file:

```
private void btn_font_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Font_Chooser fc = new Font_Chooser();
        fc.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: too easy. You should answer more questions!

Comment: on clicking the button, the `btn_font_Click` is executed twice. to avoid this, `btn_font_Click`should be not be present in `<Button/>`